# How to use regex in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have extracted the  column names from a .csv file and now I want to use a regex expression in order to capitalise the first letter of the word and the first letter after the `_` character. 
Example: loan_status -> Loan_Status

```
Loan_ID
loan_status
Principal
terms
effective_date
due_date
paid_off_time
past_due_days
age
education
Gender
```

This is what I have  come up with so far `(^[a-z])+\w+`

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew, this is what I came up with. 
I am wondering if there is a more compact way to do the below.

```
import csv
import pandas  as pd
import re


dataFrame = pd.read_csv('Loan_payments_data_2020_unclean.csv')

columnsDict = {"columnName": list(dataFrame.columns)}
columnsDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columnsDict)

replacedColumns = columnsDataFrame['columnName'].str.replace(r'(?<![^_]).', lambda x: x.group().upper())
dataFrame.columns = list(replacedColumns)
print(dataFrame)
```

Comment: Maybe [`string.capwords`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.capwords) will help here: `df['Loan_ID'].apply(lambda x: string.capwords(x, sep='_'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Loan_ID': ['loan_status','Principal','terms','effective_date','due_date','paid_off_time','past_due_days','age','education','Gender']})
>>> df['Loan_ID'].str.replace(r'(?<![^_]).', lambda x: x.group().upper())
0       Loan_Status
1         Principal
2             Terms
3    Effective_Date
4          Due_Date
5     Paid_Off_Time
6     Past_Due_Days
7               Age
8         Education
9            Gender
Name: Loan_ID, dtype: object
```

The `(?<![^_]).` regex matches any char other than line break char that is either at the start of string or appears immediately after a `_` char. It is equal to `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=_)).` regex, see [its demo online](https://regex101.com/r/3JWSWI/2).

Since you cannot manipulate the matched value from within a string replacement pattern, a callable is required as the replacement argument. `lambda x: x.group().upper()` just grabs the match value and turns it to upper case.

Comment: I don't understand this part ```(?<![^_])```. This is the guide I  am reading. https://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end

Comment: @bibscy In more detailed way, it is a negative lookbehind that matches a position that is not immediately preceded with any char but `_`. It means that the `[a-z]` can be matched only if it is preceded with `_` or start of string. Same as `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=_))`, but allows a shorter way of writing this.

Comment: ```Loan_ID``` is not a key, it is a column name as well. I extract the columns as a list and then I try to apply your method, but I get error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'  ```replacedColumns = list(dataFrame.columns).replace(r'(?<![^_]).', lambda x: x.group().upper())```

Comment: @bibscy Not sure what you are doing now, but note that `list(dataFrame.columns)` is a *list of strings*, and you cannot apply `.replace` on a list of strings. First, `import re`, and then use `[re.sub(r'(?<![^_]).', lambda x: x.group().upper(), x) for x in dataFrame.columns]` to use my solution. Or, use `import string` and then `[string.capwords(x, sep="_")  for x in dataFrame.columns]` if you want to use Andrej's solution. To replace column names, use `dataFrame.columns = dataFrame.columns.str.replace(r'(?<![^_]).', lambda x: x.group().upper())`